# What causes a preemptive operating system to hang?

Tags: operating-system, multitasking

Clearly the offending process will be forced to relinquish the CPU periodically, yet the system may remain unresponsive. Often happens when loading a page that has JavaScript or triggers and add-on.
Can a process prevent others to use the memory or filesystem? What else can cause a freeze?

Comment: Are you sure the operating system is hanging? You are probably looking for the fault in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you sure the system isn't just thrashing?

Comment: Ok lets get the definitions straight: In computing, a hang or freeze occurs when either a computer program or system ceases to respond to inputs. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_%28computing%29). Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Any reason for down vote? Also up vote for  gnasher729 who clearly didn't understand the question?

Comment: Crappy drivers, usually...

Answer (score 1):

If the system "hangs" as in comes to a complete stop, the cause is an operating system bug.

If the system becomes non-responsive, the cause is usually resource starvation. The CPU is one resource. However, it is relatively simple to manage. An operating system managements many other resources as well. Memory is one such resource. However, there sub-resources within memory. Most operating systems maintain their own "heaps" (usually called "pools"). These can be paged or nonpaged. If your system runs out of non-paged pool and process start doingI/O requests requiring non-paged pool things come to a stop.

Add to that devices and device paths. 50 processes writing to a single disk will be slower than 50 processes writing to 20 different disks.

Page file space is another shared resource.

It's all about resource management.

Comment: Looks like the word "hang" does not have a precise definition as to whether it exclusively means "complete stop" or includes temporary unresponsiveness. I did not mean it to be necessarily unrecoverable stop. Wikipedia definition I linked in the comments also is consistent with that, ie it considers a process thrashing and hogging resources also a case of "hang".

Answer (score 0):

Preemptive scheduling prevents a process to monopolize CPU but tasks for that process can still be queued for other resources (memory, disk, network) making those resources temporarily inaccessible. A process that has very high frequency IO, such as one that's loading large files to memory (especially on slow hard discs) can bring the system to crawl.